# use python to create a hyperlink leading to a specific bookmark at ms office word. ( folium map marker point)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, hyperlink, folium

I have created a map with markers using folium.
At the popup of the marker I have managed to create a hyperlink to a "test_word" that is supposed to open and go to a specific "exixting_bookmark" of a ms word file:

```
folium.Marker([lat,long],popup= ("<a href=\"file:///C:/Users/.../test_doc%23**existing_bookmark**\">test_word</a>",
                              icon=folium.Icon(color='darkred')).add_to(m)
```

the problem is that when I click on the link, it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should use double quotes inside single quotes:

```
folium.Marker([lat,long],popup= ('<a href=\"file:///C:/Users/.../test_doc%23**existing_bookmark**\">test_word</a>',
                              icon=folium.Icon(color='darkred')).add_to(m)
```

The general format for popup attribute is:

```
popup='<a href="myurl" target="_blank">mytext</a>',
```

where `target="_blank"` forces the browser to open the url in a new tab.